# Can the direct path not be the shortest distance?

Tags: networking

I know this question sounds silly, but I've been reviewing distance vector tables from this [site](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/455/Syllabus/5a-routing/distance-vec1.html)

Specifically this example where the direct path is longer than an indirect. Is this possible and if so, what are the conditions for this to occur?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a better question on the programmers or mathematics sites.

Comment: 1) Speed of the network btw G-F 2) Avg load on interface where G meets F

Comment: Edges are weighted, not necessarily by physical distance.

Comment: I was considering asking this on stackoverflow, but that site suggests code and this site explicitly said networking questions, so I figured this might be best.

Comment: @SparKotॐ What exactly do the numbers represent if not physical distance?

Comment: I think you are confusing a few things. the variable you are asking for, is built into the weights. determine how the weights are calculated, and you have your answer. you have presented a math problem as a networking problem, and the reality is based entirely on the characteristics of the network.

Comment: @krikara  Can you add more detail to the question that makes it a more real, solvable question, and less of a thought project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path is not *longer* it is more *costly*. In the example you have posted, the edges are weighted. The table shows the *cost* of each path. Since the direct edge has a weight of 7, the direct path has a cost of 7. The indirect path has a cost of 4+1=5 so it is less costly even if it is shorter.

I don't know what kind of network you are describing so I cannot know what these weights represent but that is why the cost is cheaper for the indirect path. The weights could, fir example, refer to network speeds. So, if F->D->G takes 5 seconds and F->G takes 7, the indirect path is faster because it goes through a faster network.

Comment: Ahh okay. It seems kind of confusing how they label them as Distance tables when the edges aren't distances lol.